# rearranging controls after navigationbar is hidden

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios

The main view of my app is a UImageView and a NavigationController, which is hidden.  I'm using Monotouch.Dialog to create a settings screen, which is working well.

I have arranged the UIImageView to overlap the NavigationController, so that it reaches all the up to the top of the viewable area.

My problem is that when I come back to my main view, and hide the NavigationController, it looks like the UIImageView has been automatically "pushed down" so that it isn't overlapping anymore. It doesn't look like there are any Dock/Anchor properties for the visual controls, so is there a programmatic way to put the put UIImageView back to where it was originally?

Sorry if this is a noob question, I am a longtime C# program, but have literally never booted a Mac of any kind until this month, so I'm finding the Monotouch learning curve a bit tough early on.

Comment: I think if you posted some example code it would help.  It sounds like there is probably a better way to go about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There actually are some dock/anchor properties for visual controls. They are also commonly used when working with device orientation changes.

In Xcode, click on the image that you are having issues with and on the right side you should see the properties window. At the top of that window, click to the next tab over (something that looks like a ruler), where you can adjust positioning and such.

But back to the problem at hand, it seems like you are hiding a navigation controller on the main view, but it appears after you push something onto the view stack with the navigation controller (correct me if I'm wrong). All you have to do to fix this is on each controller's XIB change the "Simulated Metrics" property in the properties panel on the right-hand side to "Navigation Bar" or "Tab Bar" (if you were using one). This will help you position things correctly so that it will appear correctly. Note that this does not actually create a navigation bar, but simply allows you to see what it will look like when you programmatically push the view and it appears.

So in summary, just modify the two XIBs to handle the image differently and your problem should be resolved!